# Bryntum Gantt: How can I render a gantt to a div?

Tags: javascript, extjs, gantt-chart

Gantt is rendering on body tags by default, so I am doing it on a div. Putting the right code by modifying `js/advanced/Application.js` and `js/advanced/view/MainViewport.js` but still not working. My code is below

`js/advanced/Application.js`

```
me.mainView = me.getMainViewportView().create({
    renderTo : 'ext-gantt-div',
```

`js/advanced/view/MainViewport.js`

```
Ext.define("Gnt.examples.advanced.view.MainViewport", {
    extend      : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
```

`index.html`

```
< body >
    < div id="ext-gantt-div" >< /div >
< /body >
```

There is no error showing in the console, even data is showing in the console from json file but nothing is showing in the browser.

What can I do now?

Comment: The reason I removed the `PHP` tag is because there is no `PHP` at all in your question. The reason I removed the `JavaScript` tag is because you are using a specific javascript library named `extjs`.

Comment: You can show us where you have provided your Panel with a width and a height. Both default to zero, which would look exactly as if the gantt isn't shown.

Comment: thank you for your concern.. this is the point I have no idea that what is that panel, actually I am developing a website in custom PHP and want to put this gantt in a page.. so please tell me what is that panel and where and how to put that..

Comment: @Alexander I am waiting for your help ;) Kindly tell me about panel that how and where to use

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define a height/width on your Gantt panel:

```
Ext.define("Gnt.examples.advanced.view.MainViewport", {
    extend      : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    width:500,
    height:500,
```

Comment: hello, there is one problem now, when I click on fullscreen button, It shows the panel in the same width.. I mean it has to show in expanded form, full width with the screen.

Comment: You can always use `setWidth` and `setHeight` to change width/height. I am not sure how to reliably determine the width/height of the browser window, though.

Comment: OK, let me google it.. anyways thank you for your support :)